# Symfony2: looking for mechanism similar to bundle inheritance

Tags: symfony, inheritance

I'm installing carlescliment/calendar-bundle (https://github.com/carlescliment/calendar-bundle) using instruction from README.md file.

Take a look at point four of instruction. I already have a parent bundle for my own, and I know Symfony2 doesn't support multiple bundle inheritance.

How can I use calendar-bundle in my own without inheritance, but in a similar way?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate bundle that will inerhit from calendar-bundle one and use the features of "brand new bundle" inside the "old one".

To do that I recommend you to define services and use them: it's very trivial.

For what it's worth I suppose that symfony2 use "single" inheritance only because, generally, a bundle is strictly related to some functionalities that could be grouped togheter. If you have a general bundle - and I suppose that 90% of symfony2 "users" have - that does pretty much everything of your webapp, to decouple it into small-separate bundles to do what I suggest could be very difficult.